# Class has no instance setter 'id='

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart, I am getting this error while trying to override a property like this

```
var newId = state.myMatches[0][0].id = 90;
```

I am getting this error

```
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: Class 'DivMatches' has no instance setter 'id='.
flutter: Receiver: Instance of 'DivMatches'
flutter: Tried calling: id=90
```

There is no properties that private. All are public. Any help what's happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking up `state.myMatches[0][0]`, which is apparently an instance of `DivMatches`. Then you try to assign 90 to the `id` property of that object, but `DivMatches` does not have any `id` setter, so the assignment fails with a `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: "DivMatches does not have any id setter, " would you explain a bit please? I have id property in DivMatches so what is the setter here? Do I need to write some extra functions? How to set up a setter? Thank you

Comment: I'd rather ask what you are trying to achieve here, because you are doing an assignment to the `id` property, and that property is not assignable. It's not clear from that what the underlying problem is. You can add a setter `set id(int value) { ... }` or, if the `id` is a final variable, make it a non-final variable, but that only works if it's your own library.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is the detailed question. Please have a look and see if you can guess, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413534/how-to-update-a-property-of-a-list-in-flutter-redux

thank you

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I solved it. Yes, it was final. And final is not changeable so was getting this error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of your setup, but if anyone else is getting this, I removed "final" from my mapping setup variable, and it worked.

Comment: Excellent. I was hang for 2 days then my issue solved. Awesome solution.