# how to update a property of a list in flutter redux

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart, flutter-redux

I am trying to update some property in flutter redux but i am getting the following error

```
Class 'DivMatches' has no instance setter 'id='.
```

Here is my state class

```
class AppState {
  var demoState;
  List myMatches;

  AppState({this.demoState, this.myMatches});

  AppState copywith({demoState, myMatches}){
  return AppState(
     myMatches : myMatches ?? this.myMatches,
     demoState: demoState ?? this.demoState,
  );

 }
}
```

My action looks like this

```
class UpdateDivResult{ // update the div result by id
  dynamic id;
  UpdateDivResult(this.id);
 }
```

My reducer looks like this

```
   var newMatch = state.myMatches[0][0];
    newMatch.id = 223;

    return state.copywith(
       myMatches: newMatch
    );
```

Please help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, I made my variables final in json serializeble. removing final will allow you to update.